# Synthesizable averaging scheme

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, synthesis

Looking for a clever solution (writing in Verilog)

Let’s say I have two 8 bit values, and each value has an 8 bit score, for a total of four inputs, and I want to combine the two values into one 8 bit value based on the scores. Hypothetically, the simplest way would be

((score1*value1)+(score2*value2))/(score1+score2)

However, it seems to me this is not “easily synthesizable” because of the division by values that are not powers of two.

Anyone have clever ideas to write a code that would serve this function that is synthesizable? I don’t have specific definition for this fusion in mind,  but it has to be synthesizable. I am also ok with less possibilities to fuse the values, meaning that I am ok with say, only 128 ways of fusing the values

Comment: What you are describing is called weighted arithmetic mean [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)

Answer (score 2):

The most direct solution would probably be to use a lookup table for \$\frac{1}{score1+score2}\$.

That would mean that you only need two adds and three multiplies.

If you need a result every clock, you'd have a three-stage pipeline:

- In the first stage, compute

  - temp1 = score1 × value1
  - temp2 = score2 × value2
  - temp3 = score1 + score2
- In the second stage, compute

  - temp4 = temp1 + temp2
  - temp5 = 1/temp3 (table lookup)
- In the third stage, compute

  - result = temp4 × temp5

Comment: But the value for 1/(score1+score2)is less than one, and I am working in binary, so how would the LUT look?

Comment: Fixed-point binary numbers are not limited to representing integers only. In this case, the output of the LUT would represent fractions in the range \$\frac{0}{256}\$ through \$\frac{255}{256}\$. When you multiply this with temp4, the high half of the product is your result. (i.e., discard the 8 LSBs)